# Diagnose message from phone to android dropped due to APP_MSG_BUSY?

Tags: pebble-sdk, pebble-appmessage

I'm trying to send a message from an Android companion app to a Pebble watchface app, but this fails with an `APP_MSG_BUSY` error.  Reading the logs, I can reconstruct the following sequence of events, which is happening repeatedly:

1. Pebble app calls `app_message_outbox_send`.
2. Android companion app receives `PebbleDataReceiver.receiveData` call.
3. Android companion app calls `PebbleDataReceiver.sendAckToPebble(context, id)`.
4. Pebble app receives `outbox_sent` call.
5. Android companion app does some work which takes less about 70ms.
6. Android companion app calls `PebbleKit.sendDataToPebble`.
7. Pebble app receives `inbox_dropped` call with `APP_MSG_BUSY`.
8. `adb logcat` shows the following warnings:

> Pbl     : [AppMessage]  there is not UUID for transactionId : -1
>   Pbl     : [JsInAppMessageHandler] sendAckNackToJs: run: can not send ack message to javascript code because uuid is null

`APP_MSG_BUSY` suggests there is an incoming or outgoing message in progress.  However, you can see from the events above that there is no outgoing message.  Also, this is happening for every incoming message, even the first that the Pebble app receives after restarting.

Can anyone offer some insight into what's going on here?

Answer (score 0):

I found my mistake: when I called [`app_message_open`](https://developer.pebble.com/docs/c/Foundation/AppMessage/#app_message_open), I passed a value for `size_inbound` that was too small to receive any of the messages that were being sent.  Unfortunately, the [`AppMessageResult`](https://developer.pebble.com/docs/c/Foundation/AppMessage/#AppMessageResult) given to my inbox_dropped function wasn't `APP_MSG_BUFFER_OVERFLOW` as one might expect, but `APP_MSG_BUSY`.

Now for sheer speculation: what might have exacerbated this was that `size_outbound` was large enough.  In fact, my mistake was swapping the `size_inbound` and `size_outbound` arguments.  Maybe, by some logic, it didn't make sense to send `APP_MSG_BUFFER_OVERFLOW` because at least one of the buffers was large enough?